# Intellij 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have installed maven on my pc and if I type "mvn --version" in the cmd, I get:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T14:57:37+03:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\mmmm\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

The problem is that from Intellij, if I try to do a mvn clean install from the terminal, I get "'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

My system variables contain these:

```
M2_HOME = C:\Users\mmmm\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
Path = %M2_HOME%\bin
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you configured the Maven home directory under `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven`?

Comment: yes, I have put this as home:C:/Users/mmmm/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin/apache-maven-3.3.3

Comment: Have you restarting the IDE after you had installed the Maven? Also if you are using Toolbox app try restarting it, then starting the IDE.

Comment: Can you show us your path ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have also installed JDK 1.8 and Maven3 as below:

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_121

>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\SDK\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\java\jdk1.8\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MS932
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I found the problem is **the environment variables of terminal**:
[image]

Copy your **bin path of JDK and Maven** into it!! And then restart your Terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that was fixed after I pointed M2_HOME to Intellij's maven plugin path instead of pointing to a path associated with a separate maven installation.

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3"
```

I also added %M2_HOME%\bin to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

restart your computer and then idea will update the system enviroment variables；
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuGFC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, solved by just restarting intelliJ

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an environment variable M2_HOME - C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.6
2. Add %M2_HOME%\bin to PATH
3. Restart intelliJ